# C# Displaying every other number from a user in a console app

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application, indexoutofrangeexception

I need to write a console app that asks the user how many number (double) to enter. After accepting that many numbers, display every other number entered. There always seems to be an error when I try to use a double. I also get this error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array."
after the the for loop has gone through the last loop for this line

`myArrai1[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

in the first for loop

this all the code I have been able to try to brainstorm with.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Item Count: ");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] myArrai1 = new int[number];
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Number " + i.ToString() + ": ");
                myArrai1[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Every other number entered: ");
                Console.WriteLine(myArrai1[i += 2]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: every other number meaning, print one and skip one?

Answer (score 0):

Not too far off, main changes to fix fix this was loop#1 was set to 0 index to prevent `out of range` and loop#2 was simplified by intervaling at 2 of ++.

The rest of the changes were aesthetic; I changed the input `Console.WriteLine` to just `Console.Write` to keep the input on the same line, and moved the *Every Other Line* statement to precede the output display loop instead of being written on every iteration.

```
Console.Write("Enter Item Count: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] myArrai1 = new int[number];
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    Console.Write("Enter Number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    myArrai1[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("Every other number entered: ");
for (int j = 0; j < number; j = j + 2) {
    Console.WriteLine(myArrai1[j]);
}
```